# iis_ssi.dll missing after reboot

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8

After rebooting Windows 2012 with IIS8 installed running in a shared config.

> The Module DLL C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iis_ssi.dll failed to load.
>
> The data is the error.

After adding the server side include feature again it works, until the next reboot. I hope there is another answer besides a re-install of IIS.

Option 1)dont allow automatic reboot
Error Message: Feature installation. The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed. The operation cannot be completed, because the server you specified requires a restart.

Option 2)allow automatic reboot; also stopped www service
Error Message: The request to add or removed features on the specified server failed. Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. Error 0x800f0922

Comment: Found something i want to try out! http://www.sheer.us/weblogs/?p=2309

Comment: Does not work, after reboot the shared config is back and the reinstall fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Disable Shared Config - dont forget to click the apply button :-)
2)Delete ServerSideInclude Module (also applies to WebSocket Module)
3)Edit applicationHost.config in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and remove below the globalModules element the add name="ServerSideIncludeModule" line.
4)iisreset
5)use DISM to reload the module
6)copy the shared config (only applicationHost.config) into C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
7)iisreset
8)re-activate the shared config in the iis. dont forget to click the apply button :-)